# Using registerUserNotificationSettings more than once

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit

I'm currently developing a sort of "choose your own adventure" game for both iOS and watchOS. The user, as in the traditional book, can/must take choices to keep progressing through the game. I did search a lot but I'm not entirely sure about this:

Can I call registerUserNotificationSettings more than once?.

Why I ask this?: Because I want to send notifications when a new choices can be taken for the user, I know that I can create an APNS with the payload, but that's just hardcoded, I need it to change it's content dynamically. Say to use from 1 to 4 choices (I can do that with different Categories I believe) and also change the content of the choice, but to do that, I believe I need to register the notification settings everytime I have to send a new notification, am I wrong?.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can call it as many times as you want, it just overwrites the previous settings when you call it again.

Comment: Thanks @dan I'm gonna give it a try then :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a new class this way:

```
class Notifications {

   class func display(text: String){

    let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    let dateTime = NSDate()
    notification.fireDate = dateTime.dateByAddingTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(1))
    notification.alertBody = text
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

   }
 }
```

and then you can send notification whenever you want like this:

```
 Notifications.display("Your message here")
```

Comment: Thanks Alex but that's not what I was looking for.